# Voting System in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a voting system, there will be one word and 5 options for that word. Those options are voted. Here is my model :

```
public int WordID { get; set; }
public string WordName { get; set; }
public string Option1 { get; set; }
public int Vote1 { get; set; }
public string Option2 { get; set; }
public int Vote2 { get; set; }
public string Option3 { get; set; }
public int Vote3 { get; set; }
public string Option4 { get; set; }
public int Vote4 { get; set; }
public string Option5 { get; set; }
public int Vote5 { get; set; }
```

In Word/Details, I added buttons for voting. Here they are :

```
    <dt>
       Word Name 
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WordName)
    </dd>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Vote", "WordController", new { id = Model.WordID}, FormMethod.Post))
        {

    <dt>
      1st Option
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Option1) <button type="submit" name="submit1" value="Vote1"> Vote</button>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vote1)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vote1)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        2nd option
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Option2) <button type="submit" name="submit2" value="Vote2"> Vote</button>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vote2)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vote2)
    </dd> 
}
```

Here is the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Vote(string submit, int? id)
    {
        Word word = db.Word.Find(id);


        if(submit == "Vote1")
        {
            word.Vote1++;
        }
        else if (submit == "Vote2")
        {
            word.Vote2++;
        }
        else if (submit == "Vote3")
        {
            word.Vote3++;
        }
        else if (submit == "Vote4")
        {
            word.Vote4++;
        }
        else if (submit == "Vote5")
        {
            word.Vote5++;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

When I click a Vote button, I get this URL
http://localhost:55590/WordController/Vote/1 and it says source cannot be found. Namely HTTP 404 error. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bit of ways of doing this (`Ajax` is one of them), but the simplest one would be to add link pointing to new action and pass arguments needed.

First I'd change your model to

```
public sealed class Word
{
    public int WordID { get; set; }
    public string WordName { get; set; }

    public Enumerable<VoteOption> Options { get; set; }
}

public sealed class VoteOption
{
    public int Vote { get; set; }
    public string Option { get; set; }
}
```

this way you don't have to repeat 5 time vote/option combination.

Then your view would look like this:

```
<dt>
   Word Name 
</dt>

<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WordName)
</dd>

@foreach (var vote in Model.Options)
{
  <dt>
    1st Option
  </dt>

  <dd>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Option)
      <button type="button"> Vote</button>
      <a href='@Url.RouteUrl('vote', new { wordId = Model.WordId, vote = option.Vote })'> vote</a>
  </dd>

  <dt>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vote)
  </dt>

  <dd>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vote)
  </dd>
}
```

so what I used here is a request to new route with arguments passed.

In one of yours controllers add a new method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("vote-{wordId:int}-{vote:int}", Name = "vote")
public ActionResult Vote(int wordId, int vote)
{
    //handle request here
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

**EDIT**

Here is another way using your original model without using `AJAX` (as for `AJAX` method see the other answer)

```
<dt>
    Word Name
</dt>

<dd>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.WordName)
</dd>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Vote", "Word", new { id = Model.WordID}, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <dt>
        1st Option
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Option1) <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote1"> Vote</button>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vote1)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vote1)
    </dd>

    <dt>
        2nd option
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Option2)<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Vote2"> Vote</button>
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vote2)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vote2)
    </dd> 
}
```

change YOURSCONTROLLER to controller where this method will be placed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Vote(int? id, string submit)
{
    switch(submit)
    {
        case "Vote1":

            break;
        case "Vote2":

            break;
    }

    //more logic
}
```

Comment: In your model, should Model be VoteOption ?

Comment: So you are suggesting using a link instead of a button, right? How can we do this with button? And how can we do  this using my model? Thanks.

Comment: I've just shown one of ways doing this. I will edit my answer later today to meet your request.

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer. It's not working yet. Please see my edited question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Change parameter order in your controller. See my edit.

Comment: I did what you said, but nothing changed... Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108902/discussion-between-gzaxx-and-jason).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy. You can insert an attribute to the buttons you have that helps you identify which button was clicked.

So, for your first button, you could do: `<button data-option="1" ...>...</button>`

And for your second button, you could do the same thing but the value of the attribute `data-option` could be '2'

Using `jQuery`, you can do this:

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action.

    var option = $(this).data('option');

    // Use ajax and send.

    var action = $.ajax({
        method: "POST"; // or "GET"
        url: "path/to/script", 
        data: {
            'option': option
        }
    })
    .done(function() {
        alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
    });

});
```

So, what this code does is, it detects a click, and we find out the option number and send it through AJAX to your application. What you can do is, you can use the `POST` method to a script of your application, and get the `POST` parameter 'option' that can be used using `Request.Form["option"]` in the script where you have set a path to in your `$.ajax()` `url` attribute.

Comment: What should I write for `url: "path/to/script"`? Thanks.

Comment: Your GET/POST route that calls a method in your controller

Comment: Could you please send  an example for that line? Thanks.

Comment: @jason Something like `/poll/submit/` you can have a POST request to that URL setup.